# Rename series of files with 2 extentions by help of sed

Tags: awk, sed, find, pipe

I have tried to rename some files which has 2 extensions in a folder which also has multiple folders.
For example :

```
"./3/test/us.bak.alt" 
 "./3/test/ca.bak.alt" 
 "./3/test/me.bak.alt" 
 "./3/test/mi.bak.alt"
 "./3/new.BAK.alt" 
 "./3/alt.bak.alt"
```

These should be renamed to *.BAK (so the .alt at the end should be deleted), but only if the .BAK file does not already exist.
And I tried this code :

```
 find  -name "*.alt" | sed 's/\(.*\)\.alt/mv "&" \1.BAK"/'
```

the oupt should be like this:

```
     "./3/test/us.BAK" 
     "./3/test/ca.BAK" 
     "./3/test/me.BAK" 
     "./3/test/mi.BAK"
     "./3/new.BAK"
     "./3/alt.BAK"
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: sorry, you are right .. Thanks for mentioning, actually i just want to use SED command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing several things:

1. You should limit the find search to files.
2. Your `sed` script does not replace `.bak.alt` by `.BAK`, it replaces `.alt` by `.BAK`.
3. There is a missing double quote in your `sed` script.
4. You should limit the `sed` search to the end of the file names.
5. You have a `new.BAK.alt` file in your input list.
6. You have an empty string `""` in your input list.
7. You have a `./3/test/us.bak.alt` in your desired output list, which apparently contradicts your specification.

Let's ignore the 3 last issues, they are probably typos. To fix the 4 others try:

```
find . -type f -name "*.bak.alt" | sed 's/\(.*\)\.bak\.alt$/mv "&" "\1.BAK"/'
```

If the fifth issue is a real one and you also have `*.BAK.alt` files that you want to rename as `*.BAK`:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.bak.alt" -o -name "*.BAK.alt" \) |
  sed -E 's/(.*)\.(bak|BAK)\.alt$/mv "&" "\1.BAK"/'
```

With one or the other, when you will be satisfied with the printed output, you can execute them all with a very small change if you use GNU sed:

```
find . -type f -name "*.bak.alt" | sed 's/\(.*\)\.bak\.alt$/mv "&" "\1.BAK"/;e'
```

or:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.bak.alt" -o -name "*.BAK.alt" \) |
  sed -E 's/(.*)\.(bak|BAK)\.alt$/mv "&" "\1.BAK"/;e'
```

(the `e` sed command executes the content of the pattern space).

Comment: Thanks for your time first and all issue that you mentioned.
I was writing that the important point is that i want .BAK.alt also being renamed, and you just mentioned it. but still new.BAK.alt is missing from the list

Comment: Did you try with the second proposal?

Comment: Yes i did, still the file new.BAK.alt is like befove

Comment: It works as expected here. There must be something else. Can you please first edit your question and fix the typos? And if the double quotes are not part of the file names, please remove them, they are useless. Then please, for one of the missed files, show its **exact** name and the **exact** new name you would like.

Comment: after executing the command,
with your command that you posted, no results, but with this one yes:

$ find  -name "*.alt" | sed 's/\(.*\)\.bak\.alt$/mv "&" \1.BAK"/'
./3/new.BAK.alt

Comment: So, if you execute just `find . -type f \( -name "*.bak.alt" -o -name "*.BAK.alt" \)` you do not see `./3/new.BAK.alt` in the output?

Comment: no its not listed in the output :(

Comment: I do not see many possible reasons: 1) `./3/new.BAK.alt` is not a file, it is a folder or a symbolic link, or 2) you did not copy-paste the command and you made a mistake when typing it, or 3) the name of this file is not what you think, it contains some hidden characters. Can you show the output of `ls -l ./3/*.BAK.alt | cat -v`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238146/discussion-between-saeid-herawi-and-renaud-pacalet).

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to install tools on your machine, consider using [`rename`](https://www.howtogeek.com/423214/how-to-use-the-rename-command-on-linux/) (also known as `prename` and `perl-rename` depending on distro). It is useful when you need to enact regular name change for files. For example if you have catalog holding say: `img001.jpeg`, `img002.jpeg`, `img003.jpeg` and want to change it into `.jpg` files then it is sufficient to do

```
rename 's/jpeg/jpg' *.jpeg
```