# How to find multiple files, check for duplicates and replace with bash,sed script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, find

I'm looking to  have a script, that help me to search the files with help of bash and sed command, that has extension (.bak.alt) and then change the name of the file, if its not already existent. I mean search for`(*.bak.alt *.BAK.alt *.bak)` and replace it with (*.BAK) if its not already existed and should compare the new one after changing it with the old one and then react,
if its the same content and name, do nothing, if not then change it.

i have figure something with help of a friend but its not complete.

```
#!/bin/bash

        echo " Finds something.."

        find . -type f \( -name "*.bak.alt" \) > F1.txt
        cat F1.txt
        find . -type f \( -name "*.BAK.alt" \)> F2.txt
        cat F2.txt

        if diff F1.txt F2.txt
                then echo "everythings looks good":
        else
              sed -E 's/^\(.*)\.(bak|BAK)\.alt$/mv "&" "\1.BAK"/;e'| wc -l    echo " Files changed "
fi
```

> reference:
> [Rename series of files with 2 extentions by help of sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69570171/rename-series-of-files-with-2-extentions-by-help-of-sed)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (untested) is what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s nocasematch

while IFS= read -r old; do
    new="${old/%.alt}"
    new="${new/%.bak}"
    [[ ! -e "$new" ]] && echo mv -- "$old" "$new"
done < <( find . -type f \( -name '*.bak.alt' -o -name '*.BAK.alt' -o -name '*.bak' \) )
```

Remove the `echo` when you're done testing and want it to actually do the `mv`.

Comment: Thanks Ed, this is great, but actualy i want to search for such files:
*.bak.alt
*.BAK.alt
*.bak and repalce with it with .BAK if its not already exist

Comment: OK, that's not what your script looks like it's doing. Please edit your question to provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: Is it Understanding now??

Comment: It's OK but it;d be much better if you provided sample input and expected output, especially covering cases where files look similar to your target files but you don't want them replaced and other edge cases. I updated my answer anyway.

Comment: Then edit your question to include that reference **as well** as sample input/output so your question makes sense stand-alone.

Comment: yeah you are right, it connected also to my previous post: stackoverflow.com/q/69570171/16217700